# AOS(animate on scroll) not working in fullscreen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animate-on-scroll

I have a website where i have added `AOS` animation.

```
<div class="row-div">
    <div class="inner-row-div" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-duration="1200" data-aos-easing="ease-in-out">
      <div class="teams" style="background-image: url('assets/images/sample.jpg');">
      </div>
      <div class="img-div">
            Sample Text<br>Sample Text
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inner-row-div" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-duration="1000" data-aos-easing="ease-in-out">
       <div class="teams" style="background-image:url('assets/images/sample.jpg');">
       </div>
       <div class="img-div">
         sample<br>sample
       </div>
</div>
```

and in the script tag :

```
<script>
   AOS.init();
</script>
```

whenever i minimize the browser window it started working, but if i refresh my site it never work, i also have used latest `CDN` and `js`

```
<link href="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.js"></script>
```

Comment: please double-check with `AOS` demo it will work fine or not?

Comment: i have already check with that, in my previous project also it's there, but in current project its not working. i also tried copy-pasting all the things accurately none of the animation works on full screen when open the site. but it works if i minimized the window.

Comment: might be other `js` is a conflict with AOS

Comment: how could it be confilct with other js, rest js are working fine and also there is no error in the console.